Did I bid properly against a (weak) 1NT opening?
With no one vulnerable at matchpoints, right hand opponent dealt and bid 1NT (which was alerted as 11-14).
I made a "big double" with the following 16 point hand: ♠ QJT ♡ 6 ♢ AKJT9 ♣ AJ54, intending to rebid diamonds, or lead them against an eventual NT contract.
Left hand opponent asked what that meant and partner said, "for penalties." LHO opponent then bid two diamonds (transfer to hearts). Partner passed, opener duly bid two hearts for her partner.
I doubled for "takeout." Left hand opponent passed, and my partner passed for penalties with
♠ A982 ♡ KJ875 ♢ 65 ♣ 92
The opponents went down four. They complained about being confused by my bidding sequence with the first double for penalties and the second double for takeout. They thought I was using, or should have been using Capelleti. This was my newest partner, but I thought she correctly characterized my bids.
Was the bidding sequence proper (if unfortunate for the opponents) or did someone misbid?

Congratulations on a nice result.
I see nothing wrong with the agreements, bidding, or explanations of the calls made by you and partner. Those who play a weak notrump  opening have to accept that, on occasion, they will go for a number. They were unfortunate, in this instance, to have both a very weak hand opposite Opener and no 8 card fit to run into.
The opponents have no basis for any "expectation" that you will be playing a particular defense against their system - unless that defense is marked on your convention cards or otherwise suggested by your explanations. The notion that you might be showing first general strength, willing to compete and or defend doubled, and then further showing willingness to play any suit other than the one they ran to, really ought to be expected by any partnership playing a weak notrump opening.

This is an example of why I don't like weak no trump. Opener actually had ♠ A982 ♡ ♠ K63 ♡ A3 ♢ Q84 ♣ KQT63, that is the top of a 12-14 range, only one point below the bottom of the 15-17 point range. But add any one of the four jacks to give her 15, and the value of her hand increases enormously. This may have been an extreme example, but even so.

@TomAu: I'm also a long time weak (12-14) NT player, but I'll tell you about the hand that sold me on playing mini (10-12) NT.    I opened 1N, vulnerable against not, with a 10 count, it went all pass, and partner showed up with a 4 count.  My 1N contract goes down four, for -400, and a top (at MPs), since at every other table, the opponents were in 3N, making an overtrick, for 430.  (The opponents had 13 each and neither was strong enough to double.)

I am a director and a weak NT player, for context.
One big issue with the weak NT is that you are sometimes too high at 1NT.  Not as often as people make out, and the strong NT goes for 800 into nothing too when responder's 4-count is a 1-count instead and the opponents' hands are the same.  In fact, the big losses (at matchpoints) are -200 into partscore, and +90 into +110 (or +120 into +140) when we preempt our own fit.  But sometimes it does, in fact. go for numbers.
One of the benefits of the weak NT (especially in a strong NT world) is that the opponents frequently let you off the hook, either in the auction or in the play, when you're "too high with the opening bid".  Sometimes they can't legitimately work it out.  Sometimes they have bad defences, or bid them poorly.  Sometimes they slip a trick in defence (and 1NT-X-all pass is very hard to defend, almost as hard as 1NT-all pass) and that's the difference between a -200 zero into a +180 top, or an -500 zero into a -300 top, or (if undoubled) a -150 zero into a -100 average-plus.
But not always, and you take what you're given.  If you aren't willing to take your system losses (and wins) with an even keel, stop playing an anti-field system. Don't take it out on the opponents.
Now, as a director.
You are allowed to play whatever defences are legal against their NT, provided you can explain them properly.  You are allowed to not play what they do, or to play their defence but with different continuations.
That includes a big double (which many, on both sides, think needs to be balanced.  No, it just has to take 7 tricks in NT with partner).  It includes playing that in a Cappelletti framework.
There's also nothing wrong with playing penalty doubles in one situation and takeout doubles in another, even on the same hand - in fact, a very common agreement is "XXX":

First double is cards
Second double (by either partner) is takeout
Third double is penalty.

So those playing that style would have the same auction.
Here, the weak NT pair got into a bad situation that your system was able to take advantage of.  No sympathy there, it happens.
However, note the "you can explain them properly".  That means Alerting as is proper, and explaining fully(*).  If they didn't ask about the double of 2♥ , and just assumed that meant that you had the trump stack, that's their lookout.  However:

if they did ask about the double, and
it wasn't clear from the explanation that it was for takeout, and
they played for you to hold the trumps rather than partner, and
they would have scored better (even if -500 instead of -800, but especially if -300 instead of -800) had they played for your partner to hold the trump stack;

then the Director should be called, and should award an adjusted score.  But note that they aren't entitled to that better score, unless all the conditions are met (and the Director was called, and the Director determined that all conditions were met).
"The opponents bid badly/didn't bid like we would and we got a bad score" - fine.  "The opponents didn't have what we assumed they would have for the auction" - fine.  "The opponents explained their agreement badly, and we played wrong as a result" - not fine.
(*) I think you play in North America? In the ACBL, the first double is "penalty or card-showing" and not Alertable; the second double is not Alertable, no matter what it means, except in very rare situations (neither "penalty" nor "takeout" fit those exceptions).  The rest of my statement assumes your partner Alerted neither double, and that that was correct.

The opponents asked my partner for the meaning of my first double. She said (correctly) that it was meant for penalties. They did not ask about the second (takeout) double.
